# jQuery Flip Plugin: Flip a div once (Diff Content) on mouse enter / Flip back on mouse leave

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, mouseenter, mouseleave

Been looking for a solution for this for a while but cannot grasp it or find it.
I started using [hover-quickflip plugin](http://dev.jonraasch.com/quickflip/examples/hover-quickflips).
but its conflicting with a load of other scripts on my page. +you dont have and config on the div/flip content

Can anyone please help!

I used this but it just spins on hover, maybe this just needs a little tweak

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('.sponsorFlip').hover(function(){
    // $(this) point to the clicked .sponsorFlip element (caching it in elem for speed):

    var elem = $(this);
        // Using the flip method defined by the plugin:

        elem.flip({
            direction:'lr',
            speed: 350,
            onBefore: function(){
                // Insert the contents of the .sponsorData div (hidden
                // from view with display:none) into the clicked
                // .sponsorFlip div before the flipping animation starts:

                elem.html(elem.siblings('.sponsorData').html());
            }

        });

  }, function() {$(this).revertFlip();});

});
```